# How to set routerLink queryParams to property value?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I need to set the `[queryParams]` for a `routerLink` by means of a component property, that is

```
@Component({
   ...
   template: '<a [routerLink]="..." [queryParams]="queryParams | async">...</a>
   ...
})
export class MyComponent {
   ...
   queryParams: any;
   ...
   constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.queryParams = route.queryParams;
      ...
   }
}
```

But that approach doesn't work, there are no query params appended to the route. What am I missing?

Comment: does `async` pipe really needed there?

Comment: What value does `this.queryParams` have?

Comment: It's a `BehaviorSubject`, if I subscribe to it and log to console I get `Object {datum: "19-10-2016"}
datum
:
"19-10-2016"
__proto__
:
Object`

Answer (score -1):

You can append query paramerts youing this correct syntax

```
  this.router.navigate([yourRouteName], {queryParams:{ida:1,Idb:2,Idc:3}});
```

or

```
<a [routeLink]="yourRouteName, {queryParams:{ida:1,Idb:2,Idc:3}}"
```

then you can receive query parameter using the bellow syntax

```
import { Router, Route, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';    
ngOnint{
        this.IDA= this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams["Ida"];
        this.IDB= this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams["Idb"];
        this.IDC= this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams["Idc"];
    }
```

Hope this will help you.